# Install listings package manually

Tags: listings

How do I install the **listings** package manually ?. With other packages I used to download all the files needed and copied in the right folders and then refreshing the packages and it worked perfectly, but some of the files I need now for this package is  **listings.sty** and **lstlang1.sty**, but I don't find them anywhere on the net , the folders contain anything but those files. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is there a something like `listings.ins`? If yes, then run as user with right permissions `pdflatex listings.ins`. This should generate the missing files

Comment: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings And what @ChristianHupfer said.

Comment: If @ChristianHupfer's solution doesn't do the trick, it would probably help knowing which OS and which Tex distribution you are using, there are differences - as far as I know - how for example MikTeX and TeXLive handle this even on the same OS.

Comment: thanks Yes  , there's a listings.ins I'm sorry but how do I run it? ,well I have a program called Texmaker , do I open it and then click 'pdflatex'? , I'm sorry , I'm kinda confused because I never needed to do it this way

Comment: my OS is windows XP

Comment: @james: If you use Windows and TeXLive/MikTeX, the package should be installed normally without any problems. Do you have some reasonably fresh installation of TeX?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer well , my miktex is kinda old and the link for the repository file says that it's not supported anymore , can I change it? If so , could you please give me the link

Comment: Well, what does 'kinda old'mean? One year, two years, a decade? I do not know the precise dependencies of `listings` on other packages, but I fear, installing a new `listings` version over an (outdated) MiKTeX distribution will fail. Consider to update the whole bunch of TeX instead

Comment: it says "5 years old " or something

Comment: @james: That is too old, in my point of view.

Comment: MiKTeX under Win then: Open the Update(Admin) link - which should be somewhere under Programs and update all packages (which, if you've never done it can take a bit :D) and try compiling again. If not, open the Package Manager(Admin) link and search for "listings" and (re)install it via the Wizard.

Comment: @BMWurm thanks for replying but the wizard doesn't work ,  the online repository is too old

Comment: Ouch... hmmm, try using the "Let me choose a remote package repository" option and pick a university near you or any you like really, because I seem to recall choosing a new repository site automatically reloads the package information (since the Wizard needs to know which repositories exist there I guess).  Other than that, completely deinstalling MiKTeX and installing the newest version might be the only option - and arguably cost a bit of time at the moment but pay off in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You *definitely* should install the latest version of MiKTeX.I suggestyou first make a list of the installed packages with your present version. Then go to[MiKTeX's download page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5mkb.png), wher you'll can choose between a *basis installer (32bit)* or a *basic installer (64bit)*. Download the one you want and follow the instructions.

[image]

When installation is finished, launch the `package manager` to add the packages you're interested in that are not part of the basic installation. It's not important if you forget to install some of them: if they're used in the preamble of one of your files, they will be downloaded *on the fly* when compiling.

[image]

If you don't want to install a new version of MiKTeX, you could download from CTAN a ready-to-install package `listings-tds-zip` (such files are to be found in the `install` directory). However such a file has not been made, but you can download the (almost) equivalent from MiKTeX's directory on CTAN, say [here](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/).

You download `listings.tar.lzma` in a directory of your choice, and uncompress it; you get a `listings.tar` file, uncompress this last one and you copy the contents of the resulting `texmf` directory at the root of your `TeXMFLocal`root. If you don't have one, create it first, wherever you please, and declare it a root via `MiKTeX options` (root tab):

[image]

Finally refresh the FNDB. Lisings is now ready to use.

Comment: Thanks for replying , definitely I would try that too , you know , I 'm trying to run listings.ins and it says that my internet settings may change , should I proceed?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea: I never installed listings, and never had such a message on installing other packages myself. However there are **2** .ins files. Maybe the compilation order is important. I'll add another, simpler way to my answer in a moment.